# Custom Asymmetric Cryptography Algorithm

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, encryption, cryptography

I want to use an asymmetric cryptography algorithm, but I need it have short Key Size(not like RSA which is at least 384).
I need it to be about around 20.
Is it possible?

Comment: The shorter the key, the quicker the code will be broken.  A 20 bit key would be broken in seconds even with the slowest decryption algorithms.

Comment: Can you explain *why* you want to do this seemingly crazy thing?  What possible value is *strong encryption* with a *weak key*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to have a short key size.

**1. With RSA**

A RSA public key consists in a big number *n* (the "modulus") and a (usually small) number *e* (the public exponent). *e* can be as small as 3, and in a closed setup (where you control key generation) you can force the use of a conventional *e*, the same for everybody. A typical size for *n* is 1024 bits (i.e. 128 bytes).

*n* is the product of two prime numbers (*n = p*q*). Knowledge of *p* and *q* is sufficient to rebuild the private key (nominally a value *d* which is a multiplicative inverse of *e* modulo *p-1* and *q-1*). Assuming that *n* is known, knowledge of *p* alone is sufficient (if you know *n* and *p*, you can compute *q* with a simple division). For proper security, *p* and *q* should have similar sizes, so even by taking the smaller of the two, you still need to store about 512 bits or so -- that's 64 bytes).

It has also been suggested to select a small *d* (the "private exponent"). But this makes *e* essentially random, hence large; you can no longer use a conventional small value for *e*. This basically doubles the public key size. Also, forcing a small *d* can make the key weak (it has been shown to be the case when the size of *d* is no more than 29% of the size of *n*, but that does not prove in any way that a *d* of 30% the size of *n* is safe). This is generally considered to be a bad idea.

**2. With DSA / Diffie-Hellman**

DSA is a digital signature algorithm. Diffie-Hellman is a key exchange algorithm. Both are "asymmetric cryptographic algorithms" and you would use one or the other, or both, depending on your needs. In both cases, there is a public mathematical group (numbers modulo a big prime number *p* for the basic DSA and DH; elliptic curve variants use an elliptic curve as group); the public key is a group element, and the private key is the *discrete logarithm* of that element relatively to a conventional generator. In other words, a prime *p* and a number *g* modulo *p* are given (they can be shared by all key holders, even); a private key is a number *x* corresponding to the public key *y = g<sup>x</sup> mod p*. The private key is chosen modulo a small prime *q*. *q* is known and must be large enough so as to defeat the generic discrete logarithm algorithms; in practice, we want a 160-bit or more *q*.

This means that a private key fits in about 20 bytes. That's not 20 decimal digits, but closer.

**3. With ANY cryptographic algorithm**

When you generate a key pair, you do so with:

1. a deterministic procedure;
2. a source of random bits.

For instance, with RSA, you generate *p* and *q* by creating random odd numbers of the right size and looping until a prime number is found. For a given random source, the whole process is deterministic: given the same random bits, this will find the same primes *p* and *q*.

Hence you can develop a PRNG seeded by a secret key *K* and use it as random source for the key generation process. Whenever you need the private key, you run the key generation process again, using *K* as input. And voilà! Your private key, the one you need to store, is now *K*.

With RSA, this makes private key usage quite expensive (RSA key generation is not easy). However, with DSA / Diffie-Hellman, this would be very inexpensive: the private key is only a random number modulo *q* (the group order) which can be generated with much less cost than using the private key for a digital signature or an asymmetric key exchange.

This leads to the following procedure:

- The "private key", as stored, is *K*.
- The group parameters for DSA / Diffie-Hellman are hardcoded in the application; everybody uses the same group and that is not a problem. The group order is *q*, a known prime of at least 160 bits. If you use an elliptic curve variant, then *q* is a property of the curve, hence a given.
- When you need to sign or to perform a key exchange (key exchange is used to emulate asymmetric encryption), you compute SHA-512(*K*), which yields a 512-bit sequence. You take the first half (256 bits), interpret it as a number (with big-endian or little-endian convention, as you wish, provided that you always use the same convention), and reduce it modulo *q* to get the private DSA key. Similarly, you use the second half of the SHA-512 output to get the private DH key.

The key generation is very slightly biased but this does not imply much security trouble. Note that if you need a DSA key *and* a DH key, then you can use the same group but you *should not* use the same private key (hence the use of both halves of the SHA-512 output).

How big should be *K* ? With a hash function such as SHA-512, *K* can be any arbitrary sequence of bits. However, *K* should be wide enough to defeat exhaustive search. A 1024-bit RSA key, or a 1024-bit DSA modulus (the *p* modulus for DSA), provide a security level which is very roughly equivalent to an 80-bit symmetric key. Similarly, a 160-bit group order for DSA/DH provides the same level. 80 bits are not that much; you cannot go lower than that if you want to be taken seriously. This means that *K* should be chosen among a space of at least 2<sup>80</sup> possible keys; in other words, if *K* is selected as uniformly random bytes, then it must be at least 10 bytes long. With decimal digits, you need at least 24 digits. Anything below that is intrinsically weak, and that's unavoidable.

**Standard warning:** if anything of the above is not obvious or crystal clear to you, then do not even think about implementing it. Implementation of cryptographic algorithm is tricky, especially since the deadliest errors cannot be tested (it is not because the program runs and appears to work properly that it does not contain security weaknesses).

Answer (score 4):

That's a .NET restriction on the key size; RSA can be used with any key size. It just doesn't make sense to do so.

Think about it, with a 20-bit key you can brute force the it in 2^20 attempts and that's just too easy with today's computers.

Comment: let me correct my statement, i need it to be about 20 digits.

Comment: let me correct my statement, i need it to be about 20 digits.thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider using Elliptic Curve Cryptography, if you can find a standard implementation of it. It provides the same level of protection against brute force as RSA, with substantially shorter key lengths.

The standard disclaimer about cooking up your own cryptosystems applies here, of course.